# Debug simple php while code

Tags: php, debugging

I am getting this error: "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in D:\Programas\wamp\www\away\index.php on line 18". Line 18 being the if statement.

Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks.

```
$vars = array("first_date_month", "first_date_day", "last_date_month", "last_date_day", "resume_date_month", "resume_date_day", "pay_date_month", "pay_date_day", "pay_time_hour", "pay_time_minutes");

$err_flag = false;
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($vars) and $err_flag == false)
{
    if ( (!isset($_GET($vars[$i])) or ($_GET[$vars[$i] == "0") )
        $err_flag = true;
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: Use an editor that highlights PHP’s syntax and bracket pairs. That will help you to avoid such errors.

Comment: You also shouldn't be using count() in the while loop. It'll have to re-count the elements every iteration. Save it to a var and use that.

Comment: also please use && and || instead of "and" and  "or" they are more commenly used and make your code more readible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I'm not seeing well, but:

if ( (!isset($_GET($vars[$i])) or ($_GET[$vars[$i] == "0") )

You got a really awful mixup of parenthesis and square brackets. There's no such thing as

```
$_GET()
```

Big typo you have to correct.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a mess.

$_GET is an associative array and not a function (you are using the function call syntax passing $vars[$i] as an argument). In the second $_GET there's one ] missing.

Line 18 should be:

```
if ( (!isset($_GET[$vars[$i]]) or ($_GET[$vars[$i]] == "0") )
```

Answer (score 2):

My take at it:

```
$vars = array("first_date_month", "first_date_day", "last_date_month", "last_date_day", "resume_date_month", "resume_date_day", "pay_date_month", "pay_date_day", "pay_time_hour", "pay_time_minutes");

foreach ($vars as $var) {
  if ($err_flag = empty($_GET[$var]))
    break;
}
```

8)

I assume the marked answer has... well.. answered the problems in your code, so just throwing out some optimizations:

- using foreach() instead of while/for
  is simple in many cases where we are
  just iterating over an array - we can get the value and also the key if needed.
- using the empty() function (returns true for anything null, false, 0, "", "0")
- exit the loop when you're done using break

Comment: +1 Obviously even more compact. Why didn’t I think of `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is a variable, an array -- and not a function.

It means you have to use array-access, with `[]`, to get the data it contains.

So :

```
$_GET[$vars[$i]]
```

instead of

```
$_GET($vars[$i])
```

for the first time you are using $_GET.

And, for the second time, you forgot to close one `]` ; which means you need to use :

```
$_GET[$vars[$i]]
```

instead of

```
$_GET[$vars[$i]
```

In the end, you while-loop should look like this :

```
while ($i < count($vars) and $err_flag == false)
{
    if ( !isset($_GET[$vars[$i]]) or $_GET[$vars[$i]] == "0" ) {
        $err_flag = true;
    }
    $i++;  
}
```

Note I also added `{}` arround the body of the if condition ; this way, if you ever have to add something, you won't risk forgetting those ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your line 18 `if...` to:

```
if ( (!isset($vars[$i])) or ($vars[$i] == "0") )
    $err_flag = true;
$i++;
```

This mainly because I -and this is purely personal, I suspect- don't like using the `$_GET[...]` throughout the script; assign:

```
$variable_from_GET[] = $_GET['variable_name'];
```

and then use the `$variable_from_GET` array variable in your conditions which you -I presume- you *did* since you had a `$vars` array.